# I need a button that takes me back to index 0

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick

So I have this array and i'm trying to make a button that takes me to the index 0. Not sure if im putting my variable in the right place.

ps Im still new

```
const responses = [
    
    {
      id: 1,
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 6 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      questionText: "Is this customer 1 or 2?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 7 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    },

  const homeQuestion = useState(0);

  const handleHomeButton = () => {
    const toHomeQuestion = homeQuestion;
    setCurrentQuestion(toHomeQuestion);
  }

return(
     <button onClick={handleHomeButton} className="backBtn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i></button>


)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you defined your state variable wrong.

It should be something like this:

`const [homeQuestion, setHomeQuestion] = useState(0);`

**`homeQuestion`** is the state variable that holds the value.
**`setHomeQuestion`** sets the state variable.

`setHomeQuestion(0); // this will set homeQuestion to 0` 
`setHomeQuestion(someVariable); // this will set homeQuestion to the value of the variable 'someVariable'`

It is really well explained with an example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Please give feedback if it worked or if I misunderstood the question.